# Как вытащить нужное из Array

Tags: php, массивы

Здраствуйте, я только учусь писать на PHP потому извините заранее за глупый вопрос..

Столкнулся с такой вот проблемой, у меня есть массив:

> Array (
> [0] => "user"
> [1] => {
> [2] =>    "00000000000"
> [3] =>    {
> [4] =>        "AccountName"       "test"
> [5] =>        "PersonaName"       "admin"
> [6] =>        "test1"     "0"
> [7] =>        "test2"     "0"
> [8] =>        "test3"     "0"
> [9] =>    }
> [10] => } )

Который берется из ТХТ и выводится через следующий код:

```
try {
$file = Stream::of('I:/test.txt');
$scanner = new Scanner($file);

$lines = [];

while ($scanner->hasNextLine()) {
     $line = $scanner->nextLine();
     $lines[] = $line;
}


print_r($lines);
$file->close();
```

Так вот, вопрос заключается в следующем. Как из массива вытащить нужную мне строку со значением "000000000000" и например еще значение PersonaName, а именно "admin"? И например есть две графы у меня (Номер) (Имя) и чтобы в эти графы распределялась информация (Номер: 00000000000) (Имя:admin), а если будут в дальнейшем еще добавляться к "user" новые данные, то и она так же вытаскивались.

Заранее всем спасибо за ваши ответы!

Comment: Кто формирует файл с входными данными?

Comment: Можно по конкретнее вопрос пожалуйста..? А то не совсем понял его..
Если вы спрашиваете откуда данный файл, то ни от куда, это собственный текстовый документ который в дальнейшем должен идти в базу данных phpMyAdmin в виде уже отсортированной информации

Comment: Если это собственный файл, то почему бы не формировать его в стандартных форматах данных типа json? Зачем вы придумываете свой формат с котором вы сами не можете работать?

Comment: А так вы спрашиваете про то, откуда такой формат массива? Он взят из файлов steam, не я сделал его таким и захотел чтоб именно так выглядело. Я лишь скопировал его и создав текстовый файл для тестов, вставил его туда. Мне к сожалению именно с данным форматом и надо что-то сделать из выше перечисленного.. В этом и вся проблема, что я просто не сталкивался с таким массивом никогда, потому и прошу совета и помощи, может у кого был опыт..

Comment: А что касательно цифр [1] [2] [3] и т.д., их в массиве по началу нет, это я с помощью кода который выше показан, пытался построчно читать массив и он приставил данные цифры к началу каждой строчки.
По началу же информация в ТХТ выглядит так:

`"user"
{
 "00000000000"
 {
  "AccountName"  "test"
  "PersonaName"  "admin"
  "test1"  "0"
  "test2"  "0"
  "test3"  "0"
 }`

Comment: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

Comment: Простите меня еще раз за мой недалекий склад ума, но я не вижу в той статье решения для моей задачи.. У меня уже есть документ с данными который находится у меня на пк и нужно просто спарсить этот файл вытащив нужные мне данные и я просто не знаю как, а зачем мне стим апи мне не совсем понятно..

Comment: Я подозреваю, что у вас бинарный файл. Разберитесь с его структурой и вы вытащите нужные данные. На php вам помогут https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unpack.php

Comment: Так какой бинарный файл если я скинул содержимое файла ТХТ в виде абсолютно обычных записей,  цифры же, это просто steamid. Я могу просто скрейпить данный файл и вывести например через принт все вместе, но мне не нужно все, мне нужно спарсить данную информацию вытащив только две вещи (00000000000) и (admin)..

Comment: а почему у вас в приведённом примере в комментарии так много пробелов между словами? Я подозреваю что там невидимые символы, которые вы игнорируете, считая их "обычными"

Comment: Нет, там не символы либо еще что-то, это просто красные строки, если бы я мог, я бы прикрепил фото как это выглядит в документе

Comment: Красные строки - это как раз нечитаемые символы. А кроме них могут быть и другие. Вы же не открывали файл специализированным редактором и не можете утверждать, что там нет других таких символов

Comment: Не помогло никак..

Comment: Я не знаю что вы пробовали и что делали, что вам не помогло никак

Comment: Вы посоветовали использовать мне команду unpack которая никак не повлияла на массив и до сих пор не понятно как спарсить с данного массива нужные переменные

Comment: Она и не должна была повлиять на массив. Ибо для другого служит. В документации это, кстати, есть